# How to copy all FLAC tags using ffmpeg?

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, flac

I'm using `ffmpeg` to perform audio filtering on my music library. However, it is not copying all FLAC tags (in particular, it's dropping [chapter information](https://wiki.xiph.org/Chapter_Extension)).

[Copy all tags from one FLAC file to another?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41304) has a potential work-around, but is there a way to get **ffmpeg** to copy chapter information from the input to the output?

Comment: hey, just a heads up: while using ffmpeg on linux is totally on-topic here, my experience is that the `ffmpeg` user- and hence expert-base over at superuser.com is larger. So, I'd probably wait another 12 hours for an answer here, and then move the question over, if nothing happened (of course, if someone answered or left a comment, address that.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ffprobe to export metadata from a file, into whatever format you want. In this scenario you would probably find use from the `flat` format, which just exports tags as key=value pairs,
`ffprobe -show_format -print_format flat music.flac`([here is the ffprobe documentation if you want more info on that command](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html#flat))

You can then write this metadata into a file with this command:

`ffmpeg -i flac.flac -map 0 -y -codec copy -write_id3v2 1 -metadata artist-sort="emon feat sort" flac.flac`, with metadata in the format of key=value, with quotation marks needed if a value has a space in it.